# Caption placement of a longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

I'd like to know how to remove the margin of the longtable caption (`\captionsetup[longtable]{margin=0pt}`) without crossing the margin given by the *showframe* package.

Actually, I think my caption has been shifted on the left of the page, because it has the expected width of the page.

See the figure below.

The problem appears on my computer but also on [overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com).

My version is `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.4.19)`.

Overleaf works on `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.11.22)`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{margin=4pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtable}{c}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Item} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{1}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- suite}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{Item}  \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline %\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline % \hline
\caption{Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test.Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test.}
  \label{tableau1}
\endlastfoot
1 \\
2\\
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Can you please clarify your expectation. The statement margin of the longtable caption (\captionsetup[longtable]{margin=0pt}) without crossing the margin given by the showframe package. is not clear

Comment: I used the *showframe* to see my text zones of the page.
After compilation, you'll see the caption ouside this zone, a few points shifted on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are the spurious spaces after your \caption command. They push the caption a bit to the left:

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{margin=0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtable}{c}
 \caption{Test test test test test test test test test test test test test
 test test test.Test test test test test test test test test
 test test test test test test test.}%<---
\label{tableau1}%<----
\endlastfoot
1 \\
2\\
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}{c}
\caption{Test test test test test test test test test test test test test
 test test test.Test test test test test test test test test
 test test test test test test test.} %<---
\label{tableau1} %<----
\endlastfoot
1 \\
2\\
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike... Deleted my answer... I could never find out by myself that the problematic code was not inside the MWE...